# OpenSSL s_client not detecting STARTTLS

Tags: openssl, ssl, smtp

I am trying to fetch the certificate of my mail server with `s_client`

```
$ /opt/local/bin/openssl s_client   -starttls smtp -connect corti.li:25
CONNECTED(00000003)
didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...
140735895012360:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 307 bytes and written 343 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1493391452
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

And I get `didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...`

But doing a telnet on port 25 gives me STARTTLS in the supported options

```
$ telnet corti.li 25
Trying 2a01:4f8:c17:3bac::2...
Connected to corti.li.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 corti.li ESMTP
EHLO casa.corti.li
250-corti.li
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

And

```
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

On port 587 everything works fine.

I am using postfix and both ports are configured the same way:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin -o tls_preempt_cipherlist=yes
submission inet n      -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin -o tls_preempt_cipherlist=yes
```

In the logs I do not see anything when trying to connect.

I am able to connect with `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017` on Linux but not with the same version (`OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017`) on macOS.

Any hint on what could be wrong?

**Edit**

I just found out that my provider is hijacking the connection:

```
/usr/bin/openssl s_client   -starttls smtp -connect corti.li:25 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
read from 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fe0d3802000] (4096 bytes => 82 (0x52))
0000 - 32 32 30 20 6e 77 61 73-2e 6c 62 2e 62 6c 75 65   220 nwas.lb.blue
0010 - 77 69 6e 2e 63 68 20 76-69 6d 64 7a 6d 73 70 2d   win.ch vimdzmsp-
0020 - 6e 77 61 73 30 32 2e 62-6c 75 65 77 69 6e 2e 63   nwas02.bluewin.c
0030 - 68 20 53 77 69 73 73 63-6f 6d 20 41 47 20 45 53   h Swisscom AG ES
0040 - 4d 54 50 20 73 65 72 76-65 72 20 72 65 61 64 79   MTP server ready
0050 - 0d 0a                                             ..
write to 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fe0d3803000] (25 bytes => 25 (0x19))
0000 - 45 48 4c 4f 20 6f 70 65-6e 73 73 6c 2e 63 6c 69   EHLO openssl.cli
0010 - 65 6e 74 2e 6e 65 74 0d-0a                        ent.net..
read from 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fe0d3802000] (4096 bytes => 192 (0xC0))
0000 - 32 35 30 2d 6e 77 61 73-2e 6c 62 2e 62 6c 75 65   250-nwas.lb.blue
0010 - 77 69 6e 2e 63 68 20 68-65 6c 6c 6f 20 5b 36 32   win.ch hello [62
0020 - 2e 32 30 33 2e 32 33 30-2e 32 33 35 5d 2c 20 70   .203.230.235], p
0030 - 6c 65 61 73 65 64 20 74-6f 20 6d 65 65 74 20 79   leased to meet y
0040 - 6f 75 0d 0a 32 35 30 2d-41 55 54 48 20 4c 4f 47   ou..250-AUTH LOG
0050 - 49 4e 20 50 4c 41 49 4e-20 43 52 41 4d 2d 4d 44   IN PLAIN CRAM-MD
0060 - 35 20 44 49 47 45 53 54-2d 4d 44 35 0d 0a 32 35   5 DIGEST-MD5..25
0070 - 30 2d 53 49 5a 45 20 32-36 32 31 34 34 30 30 0d   0-SIZE 26214400.
0080 - 0a 32 35 30 2d 45 4e 48-41 4e 43 45 44 53 54 41   .250-ENHANCEDSTA
0090 - 54 55 53 43 4f 44 45 53-0d 0a 32 35 30 2d 50 49   TUSCODES..250-PI
00a0 - 50 45 4c 49 4e 49 4e 47-0d 0a 32 35 30 2d 38 42   PELINING..250-8B
00b0 - 49 54 4d 49 4d 45 0d 0a-32 35 30 20 4f 4b 0d 0a   ITMIME..250 OK..
didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...
write to 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fff5d5363b0] (10 bytes => 10 (0xA))
0000 - 53 54 41 52 54 54 4c 53-0d 0a                     STARTTLS..
read from 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fe0d4803000] (8192 bytes => 26 (0x1A))
0000 - 35 30 30 20 63 6f 6d 6d-61 6e 64 20 75 6e 72 65   500 command unre
0010 - 63 6f 67 6e 69 7a 65 64-0d 0a                     cognized..
write to 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fe0d4807000] (130 bytes => 130 (0x82))
0000 - 80 80 01 03 01 00 57 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   ......W... ..9..
0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 00 00 9a 00 00 99 00   ..3..2../.......
0030 - 00 96 03 00 80 00 00 05-00 00 04 01 00 80 00 00   ................
0040 - 15 00 00 12 00 00 09 06-00 40 00 00 14 00 00 11   .........@......
0050 - 00 00 08 00 00 06 04 00-80 00 00 03 02 00 80 00   ................
0060 - 00 ff b6 e6 d5 52 4c 9e-1f 29 1d 19 a4 8a 17 b3   .....RL..)......
0070 - cd 06 7e bf 6f 68 8c b2-1d 78 21 9d 05 a1 f5 9c   ..~.oh...x!.....
0080 - 72                                                r
0082 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x7fe0d3402930 [0x7fe0d480c600] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 35 30 30 20 35 2e 35                              500 5.5
78713:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:
```

But only when using OpenSSL. With telnet I get to my machine (see above).

The question is now: why is OpenSSL different?

Comment: `tcpdump` or `wireshark` and inspect the SMTP session? E.g. what exact `EHLO` hostname is `s_client` using, and is the server OK with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> 0010 - 77 ...   win.ch hello [62
> 0020 - 2e ...   .203.230.235], p
> ```

From this you can see that openssl is connecting with IPv4, whereas ...

> ```
> $ telnet corti.li 25
> Trying 2a01:4f8:c17:3bac::2...
> ```

with telnet you are obviously using IPv6. Thus my guess is that the ISP is intercepting IPv4 connections but not IPv6 connections. You can check this out by enforcing IPv4 with telnet, i.e. `telnet -4 ...`